# setText() on a textView coming from a subClass in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, subclass, settext

First I'm a beginner in Android development !
In my app, I include a library that help me to create card UI.
In this library, you have a basic layout where there is a Title, a description and a thumbnails but you can create and inflate a custom layout for having a better filled card.

What I want to do is to change the text of a TextView coming from the sub Class, which is linked to the sub Layout. But everytime I try to invoke the setText method from the MainActivity, I get a NullPointerexception.

There is my sub Class:

```
    import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.Card;
    import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.Card.OnCardClickListener;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class CustomCardAccueil extends Card{




    public TextView TitreExtensionAccueil;
    public TextView DateSortieAccueil;
    public TextView NombreCarteAccueil;
    public TextView DescriptionExtensionAccueil;
    public TextView RareteCarteAccueil;
    public TextView DetailExtensionAccueil;


    public CustomCardAccueil(Context context) {
        this(context, R.layout.accueil_mycard_inner_content);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param context
     * @param innerLayout
     */
    public CustomCardAccueil(Context context, int innerLayout) {
        super(context, innerLayout);
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Init
     */
    private void init(){

        //No Header

        //Set a OnClickListener listener
        setOnClickListener(new OnCardClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click Listener card=", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {

        TitreExtensionAccueil = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.TitreExtensionAccueil);



    }

}
```

My Layout where there is the TextView that I want to change:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitreExtensionAccueil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DateSortieAccueil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TitreExtensionAccueil"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NombreCarteAccueil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/DateSortieAccueil"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DescriptionExtensionAccueil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NombreCarteAccueil"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RareteCarteAccueil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/DescriptionExtensionAccueil"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DetailExtensionAccueil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RareteCarteAccueil"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And there is how I try to change the content of TextView in my MainActivity, in the OnCreate:

```
CustomCardAccueil.TitreExtensionAccueil.setText("Test");
```

There is also the error I get in the logcat of the crash:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I don't understand the error because the object is initiated (correct me if I'm wrong).
Also if I try to change the text from the sub class (CustomCardAccueil), it's a success, but I need to do it through my MainActivity.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the class with something like:

```
CustomCardAccueil myCard = new CustomCardAccueil(mContext, R.mylayout);
```

The context you can get from your activity class using something like `MyActivity.this` or `getApplicationContext()`. Then you can use methods such as the class' `setText`:

```
myCard.setText("blah")
```

Comment: This seems logic ! I've put  CustomCardAccueil myCard = new CustomCardAccueil(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.accueil_mycard_inner_content);
in my main activity, myCard.TitreExtensionAccueil.setText("test"); this in my main Activity (in onCreate) but I get the same error ? Any tips, does I've misplaced the code ?

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void   android.widget.TextView.setText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

shows that you invoked `setText()` on a **null** object, so did you initialize `CustomCardAccueil.TitreExtensionAccueil` and how?

Comment: Yes, there is how I've initialized:  public TextView TitreExtensionAccueil;
in customCardAccueil.java and   TitreExtensionAccueil = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.TitreExtensionAccueil);
in the same class

Comment: you must make sure that setupInnerViewElements() is called before referencing TitreExtensionAccueil

Answer (score 0):

Your TitreExtensionAccueil is said to be null when you are trying to set the text.
You may want to point out where are CustomCardAccueil.TitreExtensionAccueil.setText("Test"); is called for better respond to your question.

Comment: Sorry, stack has buged and has deleted one word ! In the onCreate method of my mainActivity !

Answer (score 0):

your problem is or you are not using the proper instance for the class `CustomCardAccueil`, as you declared and initialized the `TextView` through it, So, even you have to make an instance from the class or to make the `TextView` declared as `static` variable, but make sure you run the method called `setupInnerViewElements()` before trying to set the `TextView` value.

**UPDATE:**

to get the current window view through some layout:

```
View global_view = getWindow().getDecorView(); // use that in the MainActivity to get the view
```

then, pass that `view` to your method `setupInnerViewElements()` and simply create the view with it not with `ViewGroup`:

in your MainActivity:

```
CustomCardAccueil mCard = new CustomCardAccueil(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.accueil_mycard_inner_content);
mCard.setupInnerViewElements(parent, global_view);
```

in your `setupInnerViewElements()` method:

```
 @Override
    public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {

        TitreExtensionAccueil = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TitreExtensionAccueil);

    }
```

Comment: This seems good to me but I don't find which params I've to put to setupInnerViewElements() in my MainActivity

Comment: Ok, it's better now !
View global_view = getWindow().getDecorView();
CustomCardAccueil mCard = new CustomCardAccueil(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.accueil_mycard_inner_content);
ViewGroup parent = null; (because parent was not initialized)
mCard.setupInnerViewElements(parent, global_view);
mCard.TitreExtensionAccueil.setText("Test");

Now the error is a little different, the method invoked wich fail is android.view.View android.view.Window.getDecorView() (on a null object reference) so I assume this lines: View global_view = getWindow().getDecorView() is causing issue

Comment: @Synny what is the activity that is on when you try to call it, is it the main activity, you must call it from the currently running activity, or change it to `global_view = this.getWindow().getDecorView()` and put it somewhere in the activity that contains that `TextView`, or save the context to use it like that `global_view = mContext.getWindow().getDecorView()`

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear ! In fact this is the MainActivity that is on, but I've to change the text that is in another class (not activity) that inflate my inner layout.
global_view = this.getWindow().getDecorView() I can't put this line in CustomCardAccueil because it's not an Activity and getWindows is not recognized but after I've change it in my MainActivity (global_view = getWindow().getDecorView() to global_view = this.getWindow().getDecorView()) the error relating to the setText method is came back !

Comment: it's just I want to know, that TextView is in another layout? it's not in the MainActivity? and how you launch this layout?

Comment: Exactly, it's in another layout !
In fact this a layout that deserve to customize the basic layout of the card library.
I not really launch it, I just create an object from this class with Card card_extension = new CustomCardAccueil(getBaseContext());

Comment: I've found the answer. If you want, take a look at my post !

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer by looking at the card library and his setTitle Library (I don't know why I've not thinked to this sooner !)

In my CustomCardAccueil class, I've created a String as this:

```
protected static  String titreExtension;
```

Here is the getter and setter methods:

```
public String getTitreExtension() {

        return titreExtension;

    }


    public static void setTitreExtension(String titre) {

        titreExtension = titre;

    }
```

Again in CustomCardAccueil, in setupInnerViewElements method, I've put this:

```
TitreExtensionAccueil = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TitreExtensionAccueil);
TitreExtensionAccueil.setText(titreExtension);
```

And in my MainActivity I simply call my setter with:

```
CustomCardAccueil.setTitreExtension("test du setTitreExtension");
```

Simply as this !